# Using non English keyboard on iPhone simulator

Tags: macos, keyboard, ios-simulator, non-english

I was able to type in any selected keyboard from OSX into iOS simulator prior to Xcode 5, but now it doesn't matter which keyboard I use in OSX, it's always iOS default keyboard. I tried to toggle "iOS uses same keyboard layout as OSX" and "Simulate hardware keyboard" with no success. Deleting com.apple.iphonesimulator and relaunching simulator didn't solve the problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS8.1 Simulator always uses US keyboard layout despite german hardware keyboard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26146668/ios8-1-simulator-always-uses-us-keyboard-layout-despite-german-hardware-keyboard)