# iOS 8 keyboard extension only loading on iPhone 5 and 5s

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios-simulator, ios-keyboard-extension

I am currently working on a keyboard extension for iOS 8.  Until recently, I was testing the extension exclusively on the iPhone 5 simulator.  Upon switching the simulator to the iPhone 6(both simulator and physical phone), 6 Plus, and 4s and clicking on a text field, the keyboard doesn't appear at all.  No error is shown either.  Thinking that this was a bug in my program, I tested a new program that just had the default code, and the same thing happened.  I am using the latest OS X, Xcode, and IOS Simulators.

Comment: I'm not at work which is where the Apple machine is at, but if you go to one of the menus at the top, there's a setting for toggling the keyboard.  In the simulator they aren't consistent in which keyboard is shown... sometimes you get one, none, or both.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS8.1 beta1 Simulator always uses US keyboard layout despite german hardware keyboard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26146668/ios8-1-beta1-simulator-always-uses-us-keyboard-layout-despite-german-hardware-ke)

Answer (score 2):

There is a known issue with 8.1 that causes keyboards to not display in simulator.

> Keyboards Known Issue
>
> Additional Keyboards, including 3rd party keyboards, may not appear in
>   Safari, Maps or 3rd party apps on the Simulator.
>
> Workaround: Keyboards should be testable in Calendar, Spotlight,
>   Contacts, and Photos.

I interpret this to mean your enclosing app won't work either. My keyboard won't display in Safari or Maps, but works fine in Photos search bar.

Answer (score 0):

You have to clean the project EVERYTIME you change something in the code of an application linked to an App Extension on Xcode 6.1 (Acknowledged bug in Xcode 6.1 release notes)

Comment: I tried this but it didn't help.  Did it need to be cleaned every time in the past also, or should cleaning it once fix that issue?

Comment: No just once. Strange. Did you try to reset the simulators ?

Comment: Thanks!  I just reset it and it works now on the simulators.  Any suggestions to get it to load on my phone besides reseting that?

Comment: No idea, and I don't think that reseting the phone will change anything