# iOS 8 app does not show all keyboard languages

Tags: ios8, ios-simulator, xcode6

I've encountered strange issue. My app running on **simulator** shows only **English/Emoji** layout for `UITextField`.
BUT! The spotlight shows **English/Russian/Emoji**, and it's correct.

I use **Xcode 6.1** and **iPhone 4s iOS 8** simulator.
What's wrong?

[image]
[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS8.1 Simulator always uses US keyboard layout despite german hardware keyboard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26146668/ios8-1-simulator-always-uses-us-keyboard-layout-despite-german-hardware-keyboard)

Answer (score 0):

Dupe of [iOS8.1 Simulator always uses US keyboard layout despite german hardware keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26146668/ios8-1-beta1-simulator-always-uses-us-keyboard-layout-despite-german-hardware-ke)

As mentioned there, this is a known issue and is mentioned in the Xcode 6.1 release notes.

Comment: Cool, but what should I do?

Comment: It's a known issue.  It just doesn't work.  There's nothing you can do to fix it short of complaining by filing a radar at http://bugreport.apple.com to add to the noise to get this fixed.

Comment: Ok, I did it. Will wait for respone.

Comment: Got response from Apple, they marked my bug as duplicate of existing one. Better then nothing.

Comment: Yes, I said it was a known issue. ;)