# The application is still in English (Xcode 6.1)

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, ios-simulator

I have a little problem. After installing Xcode 6.1 does not work set the localization in the iOS simulator. My application is in multiple languages ​​(English, Czech), but even if I change the language in the simulator, the app is still in English. Before everything worked fine (and in my iPad still works). Please, how do I solve this problem? Thx

Comment: Post the code where you defined the language.

Comment: I do not have the code to define the language. I have two storyboards and when the device is set to english automatically starts the English version and if the device is set to Czech, Czech version starts.

Comment: Have you cleaned your derived data or Reset Content under Simulator Menu?

Comment: Yes, I reset content and settings under iOS simulator :(

Comment: The working solution for iOS 8.1 is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26690370/2066428)