# How to use Slidden custom keyboard on iOS Simulator?

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, ios-simulator

I am trying to use [Slidden keyboard](https://github.com/Brimizer/Slidden) on the iOS simulator, but it doesn't show up as an option when tapping in a textfield.

I have tried `Hardware > Keyboard > Toggle Software Keyboard` (**Shift + Cmd + K**)

[image]

I have added the keyboard in the preferences

[image]

But when I tap inside a textfield, only the default **English** and **Emoji** keyboards show up!

[image]

What am I missing here?

I am using Xcode 6.1, and the iOS simulator version 8.1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26146668/ios8-1-simulator-always-uses-us-keyboard-layout-despite-german-hardware-keyboard here's a similar problem. Try using Calendar, Spotlight, Contacts, or Photos to test your custom keyboard.