# iOS Simulator doesn't use the same layout as OS X

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, keyboard, ios-simulator

I would like to use my Mac's keyboard to type in text fields in iOS Simulator, but actually, with my settings, when I type the letter `A`, I got a `Q` in my text field...

Here is the settings of my keyboard in OS X :
[image: Keyboard settings]

Settings in iOS Simulator :

Hardware :

[image: iOS Simulator]

Keyboards settings in iOS :

[image: iOS]

Physical keyboards :

[image: iOS]

Is it possible to use an `AZERTY` physical keyboard in iOS Simulator ? And how to do that ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS8.1 Simulator always uses US keyboard layout despite german hardware keyboard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26146668/ios8-1-simulator-always-uses-us-keyboard-layout-despite-german-hardware-keyboard)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is a bug in the current iOS Simulator. You can switch the Keyboard in the Settings, but in Safari & Co, you still get the Englisch QWERTY-Keyboard. This Question has been answered here: [iOS8.1 Simulator always uses US keyboard layout despite german hardware keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26146668/ios8-1-simulator-always-uses-us-keyboard-layout-despite-german-hardware-keyboard)

I'll share it with you as soon as I find a proper solution or Apple fixes this, been watching out for this for a while now...

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer in the question you referenced, this is fixed in iOS 8.2